# You are given PACF for a stationary process: φ11 = −0.60, φ22 = 0.36, φkk = 0 for k ≥ 3. What time series model could have this PACF?

Tags: time-series, acf-pacf

You are given PACF for a stationary process: φ11 = −0.60, φ22 = 0.36, φkk = 0 for k ≥ 3.
What time series model could have this PACF? Identify model’s coefficients and write model
equation.

I am very confused on how to derive the model equation from just these two pieces of information.

Comment: Hint: $(-0.60)^2 = 0.36$.

Comment: Please add the [tag:self-study] tag & read its 
[wiki](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info). Then tell us what you understand thus far, what 
you've tried & where you're stuck. We'll provide hints to 
help you get unstuck. Please make these changes as just 
posting your homework & hoping someone will do it for you 
is grounds for closing.